# ggplot: How does geom_tile calculate the fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to understand how the fill aesthetic works with the geom_tile.
My question deals specifically with the case when the x and y aesthetics are factors but the fill is continuous and many-to-one eg:

```
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=color, y = cut, fill=carat))
   +geom_tile(color='grey')
   +scale_fill_distiller()
```

In all the examples that I've found there's only one observation for each (x,y) pair, so the value of the fill variable is the value of the third variable. But, in this case, there are many observations for a given (color,cut) pair.
As can be seen from the output, not all the tiles are colored equal, so my question is: **how does ggplot calculate the fill value?** Does it use the maximum of the values with the same (color,cut)? the mean? Can it be changed?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Salman, I don't quite understand what you mean...

Comment: what is `diamonds`?

Comment: It's probably the line breaks - if you move the `+` to the preceding line (or just delete the line breaks) it works fine.

Comment: @Gregor what do u think, about the answer of the question?

Comment: I think Roland's answer is more helpful than the selected answer. The default stat is `identity`, and it goes in plotting order, so the fill color plotted corresponds to the last row of data in that group. You can test that with a simple example: `df1 = data.frame(x = c('A', 'A'), y = c('B', 'B'), z = c(1, 2)); df2 = data.frame(x = c('A', 'A'), y = c('B', 'B'), z = c(2, 1))`, then compare `ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_tile()` and `ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_tile()`. Whichever is last in the row order of the data is on top.

Comment: The answer at the duplicate provides the more useful information of how to use summary function, like `mean`, instead.